# My brother was trembling with/from cold

Tags: meaning-in-context, prepositions

From refers to source or reason while with refers to togetherness. However answer given is with in this sentence and another one.( She took the gift with alacrity )
Whats the function of with here??

Comment: Interestingly, although ***with*** is the hands-down winner when it comes to prepositions after ***trembling***, the *second* most common alternative for feeling chilly is *trembling **from cold***, but the second most common preposition for feeling afraid is *trembling **in fear***. And whereas *trembling **from fear*** sounds at least "credible" to me, *trembling **in cold*** doesn't sound remotely acceptable. Anyway, if a test asks you to choose between *trembling **with/from** cold*, I'd say it's a pointless test. They're both "fine".

Answer (score 1):

The word "with" refers to a quality or condition of the subject.

> My brother was trembling with cold = My brother was trembling because he was cold.

This is not a typical way of expressing this thought. At best it is archaic, at least to my American ears. *[*EDIT:** It does seem to be commonly accepted British usage, however, judging by @KateBunting's comment below.]

Better: "My brother was trembling *from the* cold." Using this construction, the "cold" is not a quality of your brother but is an external condition that is affecting him. As to your other example,

> She took the gift with alacrity.

This works well because "[alacrity](https://www.webster-dictionary.org/definition/alacrity)" (in the sense of "cheerful readiness") describes a quality she had while receiving the gift.

Comment: "Trembling with cold" seems perfectly normal to me (BrE, 60+).

Comment: As a life-lomng US speaker, i find "trembling with cold" rather more acceptable than "trembling from the cold".

Comment: If i am not wrong. With refers here  inside cold, alacrity while from refers to outside cold environment that made him tremble. I am not native English speaker. So correct me if i am wrong